# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint in Entity Framework database first

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm trying to insert data to Database using stored procedure and Entity Framework with a database-first approach.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC to perform the operations.

Below is my model class. Here I'm using country, gender & state table is been FK to my `Employee` table.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMetadata))]
public partial class Employee
{
}

public class EmployeeMetadata
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> Gender { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        public string Cmpname { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Department Name")]
        public string Dep_type { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CountryId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Stateid { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Gender")]
        public virtual tblGender tblGender { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
        public virtual tblcountry tblcountry { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Stateid")]
        public virtual tblstate tblstate { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(tblGenderMetadata))]
public partial class tblGender
{
}

public class tblGenderMetadata
{
        public int Genid { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Gender")]
        public string GenderName { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(tblcountryMetadata))]
public partial class tblcountry
{
}

public class tblcountryMetadata
{
        public int CId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Country Name")]
        public string C_Name { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(tblstateMetadata))]
public partial class tblstate
{
}

public class tblstateMetadata
{
        public int sId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "State Name")]
        public string state_name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> country_code { get; set; }
}
```

But when I'm trying to execute my insert stored procedure, the application shows me this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CountryId". The conflict occurred in database "EmployeeDB", table "dbo.tblcountry", column 'CId'. The statement has been terminated.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProCRUD_EmpDB]
     @ID int = NULL,
     @FirstName nvarchar(50) = NULL,
     @LastName nvarchar(50) = NULL,
     @Gender int = NULL,
     @Salary int = NULL,
     @CountryId int = NULL,
     @Stateid int = NULL,
     @Designation varchar(50) = NULL,
     @Cmpname varchar(20) = NULL,
     @Dep_type varchar(15) = NULL,
     @Flag varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Flag = 'Select'
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            ID, FirstName, [LastName],
            Gender,
            CountryId, Stateid,
            [Salary],
            Designation,
            ISNULL ([Cmpname], 'N/A') AS [Cmpname],
            ISNULL ([Dep_type], 'N/A') AS [Dep_type]  
        FROM
            Employees
        WHERE 
            id = @id
    END

    IF @Flag = 'SelectAll'
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            ID, FirstName, [LastName],
            Gender, GenderName,
            CountryId, Stateid, C.Name, s.state_name,
            [Salary],
            Designation,
            ISNULL ([Cmpname], 'N/A') AS [Cmpname],
            ISNULL ([Dep_type], 'N/A') AS [Dep_type]  
        FROM
            Employees
        LEFT JOIN 
            tblGender g ON Employees.Gender = g.Genid
        LEFT JOIN 
            tblcountry c ON Employees.CountryId = c.CId
        LEFT JOIN 
            tblstate s ON Employees.Stateid = s.sId
    END

    IF @Flag = 'Delete'
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Employees 
        WHERE ID = @id
    END

    IF @Flag = 'Gender'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM tblGender
    END

    IF @Flag = 'Country'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM tblcountry
    END

    IF @Flag = 'State'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM tblstate 
        WHERE country_code = @CountryId
    END

    IF @Flag = 'Insert'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employees] ([FirstName], [LastName], [Gender], Designation,
                                       [Salary], [Cmpname],[Dep_type], 
                                       CountryId, Stateid)
        VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Gender, @Designation,
                @Salary, @Cmpname, @Dep_type, @CountryId, @Stateid)
    END

    IF @Flag = 'Update'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Employees]
        SET [FirstName] = @FirstName,
            [LastName] = @LastName,
            [Gender] = @Gender,
            [Salary] = @Salary,
            [Cmpname] = @Cmpname,
            Designation = @Designation,
            [Dep_type] = @Dep_type,
            CountryId = @CountryId,
            Stateid = @Stateid
        WHERE
            ID = @id
    END 
END
```

Also, I've tried to add a foreign key to the virtual table still show me the above error.

Comment: Did you configure Fluent API for this? Can I see your Fluent API? Please add it on the question. Specifically your relationships configuration.

Comment: No I'vent configure any API

Comment: Please include your stored procedure

Comment: So you basically left EntityFramework to configure the relationship for you based on the Attributes? Include your stored Procedure then.

Comment: Pleas find Updated Question.

Comment: Not directly related to this topic but the way your stored procedure works is horrible for execution plans. You might want to consider using different stored procedures.

Comment: So, Icnt use this procedure

Comment: Nothing to do with EF.  You're not passing a valid CountryID to the stored procedure.  Post the DDL for tblEmployee and the code that calls the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the country id you are trying to insert in employee table is not equal to the country id added in country table.

Comment: as per you answer if the key is not equal then my normal insert statement should not work. Bt when I normally execute the statement from SSMS its work as per expection.